# DeclarePackage causes shadowing problem in packages

Tags: packages, contexts

The purpose of `DeclarePackage` is to load a package only when one of the package variables is needed. This works well when the variable is needed in a notebook but causes shadowing errors when the variable is needed in another package.

Is it possible to use variables declared by `DeclarePackage` also in other packages without shadowing errors?

Example: Let's assume we have toy packages "a`", "a`a1`" and "ab`" in the Applications directory of the user base directory:

Applications/a/Kernel/init.m

```
BeginPackage["a`"];
EndPackage[];
(* Use DeclarePackage here instead of Needs or Get in order to load package a`a1` only when variable var1 is needed *)
DeclarePackage["a`a1`", {"var1"}];
```

Applications/a/a1.m

```
BeginPackage["a`a1`"];
var1::usage = "var1[]; (* -> toy example printing \"this calls a`a1`var1[]\"" *)
var1[] := "this calls a`a1`var1[]";
EndPackage[];
```

Applications/ab/ab.m

```
BeginPackage["ab`",{"a`"}];
(* Expected here is to use variable a`a1`var1 -> print context a`a1`*)
Print[Context[var1]];
EndPackage[];
```

Let's test it in a notebook:

```
(* Using inside the notebook var1 from package a`a1` does what it should do *)
Needs["a`"];
var1[] (* -> this calls a`a1`var1[] *)
Context[var1] (* -> a`a1`*)

(* After loading package ab` variable a`a1`var1 is shadowed by an unwanted variable ab`var1 *)
Needs["ab`"]
```

> var1::shdw: Symbol var1 appears in multiple contexts {ab`,a`a1`}; definitions in context ab` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.

Is it possible to declare variables by `DeclarePackage` without shadowing errors (and not to use `Needs` or `Get` inside Applications/a/Kernel/init.m?)